# Karate variables inside GraphQL Query

Tags: api, graphql, karate, web-api-testing

I'm trying to connect to GraphQL API endpoint, but I get error that is saying:

```
"message": "Validation error of type UnusedVariable: Unused variable password"
"message": "Validation error of type UnusedVariable: Unused variable username"
```

Here is my code:

```
    @first
Feature: check Sign In method by API

  Background: setup
    * url 'https://ffer232311.appsync-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/'
    * header Accept = 'application/json'
    * header x-api-key = 'dadsfdsfo4'

  Scenario: get token for certain user
    Given text query =
      """
      mutation signIn ($username: String!, $password: String!) {
    signIn (username: "<username>", password: "<password>") {
        authenticationResult {
            AccessToken
            ExpiresIn
            RefreshToken
            IdToken
        }
        emailVerified
    }
}
      """
    * replace query.username = 'user1'
    * replace query.password = 'pass1'
    Given path 'graphql'
    And request { query: '#(query)' }
    When method post
    Then status 200
    * print 'response:', response
```

Please take a look and point out where my mistake is

Comment: it works for others so it must be a problem with your specific API. talk to the devs of the back-end and show them the HTTP log from karate. if you want to ask this question again, provide a cURL sample that can be run by others, or follow this process: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue